# Using positions with jquery for mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, html, position

I want to do something like fixed position, except for all mobile phones.

Like this:

Desktop:

```
#sidebar{
position:fixed;
width: 200px;
height: auto;
...
```

And mobile:

```
#sidebar{
position:absolute;
width: 200px;
height: auto;
...
```

So i'm wondering, if I use jquery or javascript, something like if mobile: use position absolute, if desktop: use position fixed, it might work.

But I'm not very good at programming javascript etc. I just know html and css.
Could anyone help me with what codes I have to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JavaScript/jQuery.

This will check if the page is being viewed on a mobile browser and then apply the necessary changes.

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
  $("#sidebar").css("position", "absolute");
}
```

If you prefer a different method, you can check the height and width of the window:

```
if(window.innerWidth <= 800 && window.innerHeight <= 600) {
  $("#sidebar").css("position", "absolute");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using css3 you can specify for mobile devices using the following.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)
{
    position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[mordernizr library](http://modernizr.com/)** to detect if the device is a mobile or a desktop. It has a very clean way of doing things.

Basically it will add classes to your `html` tag based on the device.

`no-touch  for Desktop` and `touch for mobile`

So based on the classes defined in your HTML you can add the respective CSS definitions .

```
.no-touch #sidebar{
   position:fixed;
   width: 200px;
   height: auto;
   ...

.touch  #sidebar{
    position:absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    ...
```

Otherwise you need to check for the  `navigator.userAgent` and check for each and every property to it, based on which you would need to apply the classes. But using the library makes your life a lot more easier, avoids the dirty hacks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the real question is: how do I detect if the browser is a mobile browser or not?
There is the answer: [Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/javascript-solution-to-detect-mobile-browser)